# Measure stress of gas acting on a spherical container

Tags: pressure, measurements, pressure-vessel

How can I measure stress in a thin- walled sphere containing a gas? Is there a way to predict what the stress will be without actually needing to fill a sphere with gas? I am talking about hoop stress/longitudinal stress.

The thickness of the walls of the container is unknown at this point; I know the radius and the material ([EVOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene_vinyl_alcohol)); the internal pressure will be 10 atm. The question then is how will I know how much stress is too much for the material to handle? Would it be the material's yield stress value? Once that is found, how will I know how much of a safety factor is acceptable?

Comment: stress is never measured directly. You can measure strain and calculate the stress if you know the elastic modulus.

Answer (score 2):

Spherical vessels have a stress in the wall equal to,

$$ \sigma = \frac{p r}{2 t} $$

where $p$ is the internal gage pressure, $r$ is the inner radius of the sphere, and $t$ is the thickness of the wall, where the only constraint is $r/t \geq 10$.

Comment: I do know that this is a useful formula to use in this situation, however, the stress is unknown and thickness of the wall is also unknown. Is there a way to measure the stress in the container physically if a formula cannot be used to find the stress given the aforementioned constraints?

Comment: Are you doing this experimentally or are you trying to seek an analytical solution?

Comment: I am hoping for an analytical solution, but currently, I am faced with an equation with two variables. I am also open to any suggestions for how to measure the stress experimentally as well. Any suggestions for a resolution to this using an analytical solution would be preferred.

Comment: Do you have the physical spherical vessel already made?

Comment: I do not. If absolutely needed, I could have it made eventually if that is the only way to find the stress if analytical methods cannot be used.

Comment: At this stage of design, you need to do what is called a parametric analysis and then a trade study/decision. That one equation will allow you to sweep the thickness $t$, radius $r$, and pressure $p$ to see which combinations create a stress that is within your allowable stress range subject to a safety factor without yielding the material of your vessel. Perhaps you can simplify the study by fixing one of the variables, say $r$. Then you can create surface plots of $\sigma$ vs $t$ at different pressures to help visualize your design space. The constraint will be the allowable stress.

Comment: That is a very interesting suggestion. I know what the radius and material of the sphere will be, and I also know the pressure that will be contained by the sphere. By inputting different values for the wall thickness in the formula, I will get different values for stress. The question, then, is how will I know how much stress is too much for the material to handle? Would it be the material's yiled stress value? Once that is found, how will I know how much of a safety factor is acceptable?

Comment: You will have to know what material you wish to use. Here are a few material properties (http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/young-modulus-d_417.html). Now, if you fix the radius and pressure, you can plot $\sigma$ vs $t$ to reveal $\sigma \sim 1/t$. You will have to pick the safety factor. Usually a safety factor of 2.5 is common regarding the yield strength of the material. That means you will figure out which thickness will give you a stress in the material that is 2.5 times less than the yield strength for that chosen material. This is the engineering design side of things.

Comment: The material is EVOH (Ethylene vinyl alcohol). Why does the stress come out to be about 1/t ?

Comment: It is from the equation.

Comment: Is it possible to skip the parametric step if I were to define stress = (1/2.5) yield strength of the material and then apply to the formula: (1/2.5)yield strength of material = (pr)/2t ?

Comment: Yes. The parametric step was if you didn't know $p$ or $r$, i.e. you had more than 1 variable sweeping to determine $\sigma$.

Comment: I can't seem to find the yield strength of EVOH online. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: you should edit the question to include all the info you are adding via comments.  Some typical data for you: http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheettext.aspx?matguid=744899e4ab06482da9cf86d8f450db0d

Comment: Be aware the appropriate factor of safety depends on the consequences of failure.  Do you have secondary containment to hold the shrapnel should the thing explode?

Comment: @ agentp      Done. The yield strength was not on that chart. Do you know of anywhere that I can find it? Also, there is no secondary containment to hold any potential shrapnel. How does this change the safety factor? The consequences of this container exploding will be quite extreme as it is under high pressure.

Comment: @Hypnos, I don't think you want to use EVOH. Wikipedia says it is mostly used as a liner in pressure tanks, which means it is *not* bearing the stress. Additionally, determining the allowable working load for plastics is a complex process involving the specific creep curve for the plastic selected and the desired service lifetime of the plastic. Unlike metals, you can't simply find a number on a datasheet and use it in the equation.

Comment: @Hypnos, I'd like to add another comment, based on another question you asked, "How do PET bottles hold so much pressure?"; the reason I said that you probably don't want to use EVOH is because 10atm is a lot of pressure: ~10 kgf/sq cm. If you approximate your fingertip as one square centimeter, that means you'd have to put 10kg on each fingertip. It's not impossible, it's just that there are a lot of complexity to plastics that you could avoid by using metal.

Comment: @regdoug, It is true that EVOH is often used as a liner in pressure tanks. Shouldn't the formula (1/2.5)yield strength of material = (pr)/2t provide the minimum thickness for the walls of the container to contain the aforementioned pressure? Also, as long as the walls of the container are thick enough, the stress should not come anywhere near the material's yield stress. The reason that I am considering using EVOH is for its low permeability and low cost. If there is anything that I have stated in this post that is false, please correct the error(s).

Comment: @regdoug, It should also be noted that in a statement on the wiki, it is stated that EVOH is more expensive to produce and is not used to manufacture entire containers due to cost. This is said in relation to food containers, but I think that the same concept applies to fuel containers as well.

Comment: @HypnosStratagem yes, that should provide the minimum thickness (note that the equation is only valid for $t < 10r$) as long as you don't need to hold the pressure for a long time or above room temperature, which will cause creep.

Comment: @HypnosStratagem also note that steel has a very low permeability everything except hydrogen and is very cheap considering its strength.

Comment: @regdoug, I suppose that it an interesting coencidence that this container will be containing hydrogen then. If it can be established, through the aforementioned formula, that a thickness can be determined so that the EVOH can hold the pressure, is there a problem? Also, what would be the problem with holding the pressure for a long time if the container is never expected to exceed room temperature? Note that I am not familiar with the causes/effects of creep.

Comment: @regdoug, Also, I am not sure if working load is relavent to the container as it will not be used to lift anything.

Comment: @HypnosStratagem the working load in this case is how much stress the pressure of the gas will cause. Above a certain temperature, materials don't keep their shape, but keep stretching (usually imperceptibly) until they break. Forevery plastic that I know of that temp is below room temperature. (For reference, aluminum starts to creep at 100C and steel at 400C) I am planning to condense all of my comments into an answer this weekend.

Comment: @regdoug, I think that the issue of working load has already been addressed in the posts about yield strength providing the minimum thickness to contain the pressure and handle the stress(unless I am wrong). Do you think that this gradual stretching could be a problem for a plastic container attempting to contain a gas over a prolonged period of time? There are a multitude of containers on the market that can store water, water at higher pressures, and oxygen for a long period of time. Also, soda bottles can contain soda at higher pressures for years without needing to worry about stretching.

Answer (score -1):

Create a 3D stress tensor and calculate the known forces for a tube (easily googleable). You simply need to know the pressure inside the tube if it is in quasi-equilibrium. Given that there is no torsion it should be quite simple, but you must know the force exerted on the body. You can predict the pressure using PV=nRT assuming an ideal gas. If I'm missing something let me know and I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the known forces for a sphere be calculated instead of a tube? Also, there is no torsion (meaning that the sphere is not twisted in any way). The pressure is known for the interior of the sphere as 10 ATM. Also, if I may ask, what exactly is a 3D stress tensor? (I am a chemistry guy.)

Comment: No engineer in his/her right mind would solve this problem in such a convoluted way. Just draw a free body diagram for half of the the sphere plus half the pressurized gas. Resultant force on the circular "cut" through the sphere = $\pi r^2 P$ (from the gas) - $2 \pi r t \sigma$ (from the stress in the sphere = 0. Therefore $\sigma = pr/2t$.

Comment: It should be noted that I do not know the thickness of the container wall or the stress on the container. Unless I am missing something about the post, this would leave me with an equation with two variables (please correct me if I am wrong about this conclusion). See the above conversation with TRF for more details.

Comment: @alephzero I suppose you should fill in the experts in the field of their incorrect approach. They can be contacted at Rensselaer polytechnic, the oldest technical school in the English speaking world. By the way the stresses described are encompassed in the 3D tensor.

Comment: @Hypnos Stratagem a 3D stress tensor is just a matrix that expresses the stresses on an object in every direction with the diagonal stresses being principal and others being shear. Don't let the other comments confuse you, they are giving you equations for hoop stress etc, the tensor includes those stresses as it is the fundamental approach to analyzing a body in three dimensional space (real material behavior/understanding vs regurgitating equations).

Comment: Facinating suggestion. Shouldn't the known forces for a sphere be calculated instead of a tube as this is the shape that is being used? Also, I do not know the force exerted on the body. I do know the pressure to be 10 ATM within the container, however. Also, as there are no shear forces for a spherical container and the force exerted on the body is unknown, should the formula then be used? Is there a way to determine the force acting on the body?

Comment: @ShuddaBeenCodin I don't need some expert from a school that I've never heard of to tell me how to do this (though I've had plenty of experience of American engineers incorrectly thinking that everybody else in the world is a fool compared with them!). I've been using this example as the first part of a standard interview question for about 30 years - though most applicants with a BSc in Mech Eng are too poorly educated to solve it by *any* method these days, let alone an efficient one.

Comment: "Shouldn't the known forces for a sphere be calculated instead of a tube as this is the shape that is being used?" You are quite right. I can't guess whether @ShuddaBeenCodin doesn't know the difference, or didn't read the question properly, but either way all of his/her comments can safely be ignored IMO.

Comment: Downvoted because "easily googleable" is not an answer. Will upvote instead if a worked out example is provided. (or at least references...)